# Add input field on click react js from form object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following snippet from my react app to generate the input fields for my form:

```js
const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState({
    controls: [
      {
        network: {
          elementType: "input",
          elementConfig: {
            type: "text",
            label: "Network",
          },
          value: "Twitter",
        },
      },
      {
        username: {
          elementType: "input",
          elementConfig: {
            type: "text",
            label: "Username",
          },
          value: "@john",
        },
      },
      {
        url: {
          elementType: "input",
          elementConfig: {
            type: "url",
            label: "URL",
          },
          value: "https://example.co",
        },
      },
    ],
  });
```

Code snippet to generate Input field:

```js
 const profilesControls = (controls) => {
  const formElementsArray = controls.map((item,index) =>({
    id: Object.keys(item)[0],
    index:index,
    config: item[Object.keys(item)[0]],
  }))
  return formElementsArray;
}

  let profileField = profilesControls.map((formElement) => (
    <Input
      label={formElement.config.elementConfig.label}
      key={formElement.index}
      type={formElement.config.elementType}
      elementConfig={formElement.config.elementConfig}
      value={formElement.config.value}
      changed={(event) =>
        arrayInputHandler(event, formElement.index, formElement.id)
      }
    />
  ));
```

And a button and function attached to the button to add another set of **[network, username, url]**

```js
  const handelAddField = () => {
    const fields = [...profiles.controls];

    fields.map((item, i) => {
      setProfiles({...profiles, controls: [...profiles.controls, item]})
    });
    console.log(profiles.controls);
  };
```

With the `handelAddField`  I can see the object pushed into the controls array of the state but the input fields are not generated in the form.

**Update**

Now only one input field is generated that is URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own solution:

```js
  const handelAddField = () => {
    const fields = [...profiles.controls];
    fields.map((item, i) => {
      fields.push(item);
    });
    setProfiles((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      controls:fields
    }));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

you should all `setProfiles` for updating a state.

instead of `profiles.controls.push(item)` use:

```js
setProfiles({...profiles, controls: [...profiles.controls, item]})
```

Comment: Oh thanks I completely I missed it. But placing it inside map function is adding last input field `url` only